# send data through android app http url method on server

Tags: php, android

hii i have created an app in which i want to build a login form and attendance also i have made a website for adding attendance in php and its working fine, now i creating app but i am not able to send data through app on server i saw some tutorials also and got this code.

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {


TextView content;
EditText fname, email, login, pass;
String Name, Email, Login, Pass; 

/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    content=(TextView)findViewById( R.id.content );
    fname=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.name);
    email=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.email);
    login=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.loginname);
    pass=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.password);


    Button saveme=(Button)findViewById(R.id.save);

    saveme.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener(){

        public void onClick(View v)
        {
            try{

                     // CALL GetText method to make post method call
                    GetText();
             }
            catch(Exception ex)
             {
                content.setText(" url exeption! " );
             }
        }
    });  
}

    / / Create GetText Metod
    public  void  GetText()  throws  UnsupportedEncodingException
  {
    // Get user defined values
    Name = fname.getText().toString();
    Email   = email.getText().toString();
    Login   = login.getText().toString();
    Pass   = pass.getText().toString();

     // Create data variable for sent values to server  

      String data = URLEncoder.encode("name", "UTF-8") 
                   + "=" + URLEncoder.encode(Name, "UTF-8"); 

      data += "&" + URLEncoder.encode("email", "UTF-8") + "="
                  + URLEncoder.encode(Email, "UTF-8"); 

      data += "&" + URLEncoder.encode("user", "UTF-8") 
                  + "=" + URLEncoder.encode(Login, "UTF-8");

      data += "&" + URLEncoder.encode("pass", "UTF-8") 
                  + "=" + URLEncoder.encode(Pass, "UTF-8");

      String text = "";
      BufferedReader reader=null;

      // Send data 
    try
    { 

        // Defined URL  where to send data
        URL url = new URL("http://houseonclick.com/httppost.php");

     // Send POST data request

      URLConnection conn = url.openConnection(); 
      conn.setDoOutput(true); 
      OutputStreamWriter wr = new   
    OutputStreamWriter(conn.getOutputStream()); 
      wr.write( data ); 
      wr.flush(); 

      // Get the server response 

    reader = new BufferedReader(new         
 InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream()));
     StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    String line = null;

    // Read Server Response
    while((line = reader.readLine()) != null)
        {
               // Append server response in string
               sb.append(line + "\n");
        }


        text = sb.toString();
    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {

    }
    finally
    {
        try
        {

            reader.close();
        }

        catch(Exception ex) {}
    }

    // Show response on activity
    content.setText( text  );

       }

   }
```

and the php code i am using on server is

```
<?php 

   $name   = urldecode($_POST['name']);
   $user   = urldecode($_POST['user']);
   $email  = urldecode($_POST['email']);
   $pass   = urldecode($_POST['pass']);

   print " ==== POST DATA =====
   Name  : $name
   Email : $email
   User  : $user
   Pass  : $pass"; 

 ?>
```

and here is my xml file codes

```
<TableLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:layout_width="wrap_content"   
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:stretchColumns="*" android:background="#ffffff">


 <TableRow android:background="#758AA7" android:layout_margin="2dip">
       <TextView android:id="@+id/output"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="1px"
        android:text="@string/default_output" 
   android:layout_width="wrap_content" />
       <TextView android:id="@+id/content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="2px"
        android:text="@string/default_content"   
 android:layout_width="fill_parent" />
 </TableRow>
 <TableRow android:background="#758AA7" android:layout_margin="2dip">

    <Button android:text="Save On Web"
    android:id="@+id/save"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
    android:layout_gravity="center" 
     />
    </TableRow>

 <TableRow android:background="#ffffff" android:layout_margin="2dip">

    <TextView style="@style/CodeFont"
     android:text="@string/Name"   android:layout_width="30px"   
  android:layout_gravity="left"/>
    <EditText android:id="@+id/name" 
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
         android:gravity="left" android:layout_gravity="left"  android:width="210px"/>
</TableRow>
 <TableRow android:background="#ffffff" android:layout_margin="2dip">

    <TextView style="@style/CodeFont"
     android:text="@string/Email"   android:layout_gravity="left"/>
    <EditText android:id="@+id/email" 
     android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_gravity="left" 
  android:width="210px"/>
  </TableRow>
   <TableRow android:background="#ffffff" android:layout_margin="2dip">

    <TextView style="@style/CodeFont"
     android:text="@string/LoginName"   android:layout_gravity="left"/>
    <EditText android:id="@+id/loginname" 
     android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_gravity="left"   
   android:width="210px"/>
</TableRow>
 <TableRow android:background="#ffffff" android:layout_margin="2dip">

    <TextView style="@style/CodeFont"
     android:text="@string/Password"   android:layout_gravity="left"/>
    <EditText android:id="@+id/password" 
     android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_gravity="left"   
   android:width="210px"/>
   </TableRow>
  </TableLayout>
```

can someone tell what is wrong in this, and how to send and get data, if something is wrong that what change i have do in this thanks.

Comment: You can use volley library.

Comment: how to use it, can u please explain